# Figuring out where Torah scrolls come from

Tags: history, sefer-torah, safrus

Lets say a synagogue has inherited a lot of Torah scrolls, but doesn't know where many of them come from. How would they go about determining from which countries these scrolls hail from? Are there any websites or other resources available that talk about writing styles, parchment colors, types of letters used, etc, that one could use to determine some of the scrolls' pasts?

Answer (score 4):

As in every field you go to the professionals which work, deal or research judaica. Especially in the field of Torah scrolls they have the ability, to a certain extent, to even say which person wrote the scroll if it's from somebody famous.